# Detecting an URL change with CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm creating a software that uses CefSharp 73.1.130. I need to make some check when the URL changes or at least when the page is loading.

I've already tried a lot of things such as :

```
browser.RenderProcessMessageHandler = new RenderProcessMessageHandler();

public class RenderProcessMessageHandler: IRenderProcessMessageHandler {
    // Wait for the underlying `Javascript Context` to be created, this is only     called for the main frame.
    // If the page has no javascript, no context will be created.
    void IRenderProcessMessageHandler.OnContextCreated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame) {
        const string script = "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ alert('DomLoaded'); });";

        frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(script);
    }
}

//Wait for the page to finish loading (all resources will have been loaded,     rendering is likely still happening)
browser.LoadingStateChanged += (sender, args) => {
    //Wait for the Page to finish loading
    if (args.IsLoading == false) {
        browser.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("alert('All Resources Have Loaded');");
    }
}
```

and this :

```
    browser.LoadingStateChanged += OnLoadingStateChanged;
private void OnLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args) {
    if (!args.IsLoading) {
        // Page has finished loading, do whatever you want here
    }
}
```

But i'm not sure that i'm using it properly so i get errors everytime such as "The name does not exist in the current context".

Here is my CefSharp code :

```
    public CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
private void InitializeChromium() {
    CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
    Cef.Initialize(settings);
    browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com/");
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    this.wb_panel.Controls.Add(browser);
}
```

I'm expecting to get the new url as an output to display it in a RichTextBox

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_AddressChanged.htm

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for your answer ! But I'm really sorry to bother you but i'm quite begginer for both C# and CefSharp so I'm not sure of how to use it... I made this for now `private void ChromiumWebBrowser_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            debug_tb.Text += e.Address;
        }` but it looks like it's not the proper use

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/BrowserForm.cs#L74

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, you can use `ChromiumWebBrowser_AddressChanged` event on your code. [ChromiumWebBrowser.AddressChanged](http://ChromiumWebBrowser.AddressChanged%20Event) event is described here at the library website.

this is how you should use it:

Subscribe the event:

```
browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;
```

Define `OnBrowserAddressChanged` body to chagne `RichBoxText` value:

```
this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => richTextBox1.Text = e.Address);
```

**Done**

Here is the complete example:

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using CefSharp.WinForms.Internals;

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com")
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            };


            browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;

            Controls.Add(browser);
        }

        private void OnBrowserAddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => Text = e.Address);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's working ! I understand better now. I will come back for a upvote when i'll get the 15 rep :p

Comment: I have a last question : My software is performing button pushes when on a specific page but i'd like to set a delay between two pushes so my code contains between 2 pushes `Thread.Sleep(4000);` but the break don't take place. I guess it's because of `InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired()` as `Thread.Sleep()` break the thread ?

Comment: @lenr I don't recommend to use `Thread.Sleep` or `Task.Delay` for doing this because it will cause your form get freeze! Why don't you just use a `DateTime` variable for doing this? For example when you click on the button set a private property (eg: private  `DateTime LastClickTime {get;set;}` ) LastClickTime = DateTIme.Now, and before setting the value check the LastClickTime subtract current time is less than 4 seconds.

Comment: Okay it can be a solution but is it enough precise ? Because i use delay such as 75ms